# Issue with specific email ids in contact forms EDITED with the solution

Tags: php, html

Edited:

So the issue wasnt because of the mail validation, the certain email ids eg yahoo.com was getting rejected by gmail host because :

```
$headers = "From: $email\n";
```

So the from field generated by contact form contains email id in above case it was yahoo.com and I found out that due to Yahoo's DMARC rules gmail rejects the message. Instead I replaced the headers:

```
$headers = "From: $name\n";
```

So we've 'name' instead in from field. And now it works for the previously not working email ids.

Right now the contact form is working fine after I incorporated the above change.

---

Initially I'd used the following code to validate email ids:

```
if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", $email)) 
{ 
echo "<p>It appears you entered an invalid email address</p><p><a href='javascript: history.go(-1)'>Click here to go back</a>.</p>"; 

}
```

But then while testing emailids with hotmail.com or yahoo.com or yahoo.co.uk were shown as invalid ids. So I tried using filter_var function. In this case , the ids were accepted and form got submitted but then I didnt receive contact form details in my mailbox after submit.

So I changed my code once again as follows:

```
if (preg_match("/^[^@]*@[^@]*\.[^@]*$/", $email)){}
```

In above, I am able to receive mails with ids: hotmail.com but the issue with yahoo.com,yahoo.co.uk persists.

The contact form gets submitted without any issue but I'm unable to receive mails in my inbox when customers in contact forms uses email ids of yahoo.com or yahoo.co.uk

I've read through many online similar queries,solutions and I tried my best to implement it as above. Any additional help will be much appreciated.

Comment: form email validation of email address is not related to your receiving an email issue

Comment: Hello, when I changed the code to preg_match than only I started receiving mail with ids hotmail, otherwise initially it gave me invalid id message with ereg function, and in filter_var the form was getting submitted but no mail was received in mailbox. But when I used preg_match contact form for id of hotmail worked.As in I received mail.

Comment: So if its not related to mail validation then kindly guide me as to what do I check?